# Binding DisplayValue to a different Source than the Control's DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

Say I have Tasks and Employees, each with their respective table in the database.  There would be a many to many relationship between them, and as such there would be a third table for Assignments.

If I create a listbox that is bound to a AssignmentsBindingSource I do not have the name of the employee to display.  Is there a way to get this from a second binding source and use it in the same control?

I am currently binding to a view to accomplish this, but when an employee is assigned to a task, the view will not update the information until the edits are commited to the database and refilled.

Answer (score 0):

Run a query or create a view and use it as the datasource.